# jquery confirm not working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My jQuery is as follows:

```
function confirmRxAction(tNum) {
  var aUrl = "";
  alert(tNum);
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to close?")) {
    aUrl = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tax/executeoneTimeEx.html?tNum=" + tNum;
    $("#aRx").click();
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aRx").click(function() {

      xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: aUrl,
        dataType: "text",
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorThrown) {},
        success: function(ajaxResult, testStatus) {

          if (ajaxResult.length > 0)
            alert(ajaxResult);
          else
            afterUpdate();

        }
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
}
```

When the hyperlink is clicked the function is called and pops up this confirm message with yes or no.

When I select yes for the first time control doesn't go to the controller. The confirm popup closes but no action is taken.
So I go click the hyperlink for the second time and everything works fine.

What is wrong that prevents the action to be called on the first click?

Comment: `<script>
function confirmRxAction(tNum){
    var aUrl = "";alert(tNum);
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to close?")) {
  aUrl = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tax/executeoneTimeEx.html?tNum=" + tNum;$("#aRx").click();
 }
}
$("#aRx").click(function(){
 xhr = $.ajax({type: "POST", 
  url: aUrl,  
  dataType: "text",
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorThrown){                              
  }, 
  success: function(ajaxResult, testStatus){
   if(ajaxResult.length>0)
    alert(ajaxResult);
   else
    afterUpdate();
  }
 });
 return false;   
});</script>`

Comment: You bind the event on the element after you call the code to click it. It is like eating a pizza before you make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $(document).ready function is inside your confirm function, so the click event isn't attached until confirm function is run the first time. Try moving the $(document).ready function outside of the confirm function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you writen your code like this, but you should use it like below::

```
function confirmRxAction(tNum){
    var aUrl = "";
    alert(tNum);
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to close?")) {
            aUrl = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tax/executeoneTimeEx.html?tNum=" + tNum;
            xhr = $.ajax({type: "POST", 
                url: aUrl,  
                dataType: "text",
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorThrown){                              
                }, 
                success: function(ajaxResult, testStatus){

                    if(ajaxResult.length>0)
                        alert(ajaxResult);
                    else
                        afterUpdate();

                }
            });
        }
}
```

Just replace your function with my function.

Comment: But then he would have to have write this code twice.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm why?

Comment: Because he would need it in his click event too. Either way, your solution would be better if it was a function. Irrelevant though, since the problem is his `document.ready` is in his function, which is why it's not working for him.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm where he mentioned that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setup the click on document ready instead.  And add the confirm in the click() like in the snippet example.

```js
function afterUpdate() {
  alert("after update");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aRx").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to close?")) {
      
      xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorThrown) {
          alert("error" + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(data) {
              if (data != null)
                alert(data);
              else
                afterUpdate();
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="aRx" href="#">Click Here</a>
```